# how would SQL Server interpret this where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I'm looking at someone else's production code, and I am surprised this where clause would achieve the desired result:

```
where C1 = 'one' and C2 not in ('apple','pear') and C3 <> 'pie'
   or C1 = 'two' and C2 not in ('apple','pear')
```

C1 actually has only two values, so it shouldn't be necessary to specify both with an OR. Regardless, I think it should have parenthesis like this:

```
where (C1 = 'one' and C2 not in ('apple','pear') and C3 <> 'pie')
   or (C1 = 'two' and C2 not in ('apple','pear'))
```

Would SQL Server interpret the first statement the same as the second statement with parenthesis? If not, how would it interpret the first statement?

Comment: *Would SQL Server interpret the first statement the same as the second statement with parenthesis?* yes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: SQL Server interprets the `AND` before the `OR`. But you should always explicitly use parenthesis, for a mountain of reasons that are outside the scope of this comment.

Comment: yes, both are interpreted the same.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server evaluates `AND` before `OR`, so adding parentheses as you propose won't affect the result. However, the additional parentheses *can* make it more obvious to the reader, which is usually a good thing.

Comment: This query only works because both C2 filters were for not in ('apple','pear'). If the 2nd C2 was for example not in ('orange','grape') then this would also exclude orange and grapes from the first desired clause as well as the second which is why the parenthesis is missing and incorrectly so based on the way the query has been written.